# Magento1 - tests - phpunit compatibility

Tags: magento-1.9, unit-tests, phpunit, ecomdev-phpunit

I am currently working on a project (magento 1.9) where tests are developed using PHPUnit 4.8, ECOMDev and TechDivision/magento unit testing (https://packagist.org/packages/techdivision/techdivision_magentounittesting).

Testsuites are running without problems but yeah, PHPUnit 4.x is not supported since a long time now and that's quite annoying : that's why I would like to migrate to a stable PHPUnit version...

Issue : it seems ECOMDev and TechDivision are not maintained anymore and not compatible to newer PHPUnit versions... I tried with last stable (6.x) and with 5.5.7 and I have some troubles to run testsuites...

My question is : Does anyone of you know 1) if it is possible to use last stable/5.x PHPUnit version with ECOMDev &/or TechDivision magento unittesting 2) how to do it if 1) is positive ?

Thanks for your answers/advice :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have experience with the techdivision framework, but for EcomDev_PHPUnit I know that it is not possible to run it with PHPUnit 5 or greater.

Converting from 4 to 6 is quite an effort that will break lots of stuff (Magento did it between 2.1 and 2.2...), converting from 4 to 5 should be doable. I have recently been given maintainer status of the Github repository since Ivan has not been working on it anymore for a long time.

So I promise, if you find a way to make EcomDev_PHPUnit compatible with PHPUnit 5, I will make sure to merge it. PHPUnit 6 might be the next step then.

Comment: Thanks Fabian for your answer :)
I will take a look at it and check if it is possible to do it in a timely fashion.

Otherwise, any thoughts on a framework PHPUnit 6 compatible to test magento ?